# How to subtract 2 subdocs with the same goods_info.name with aggregate mongo

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, aggregate

> I'm trying to substract goods_in and goods_out with same goods_info.name. i've tried, still stuck, please help me

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5f1aaa902f90f940a40546fe",
        "goods_in": [
            {
                "goods_info": {
                    "name": "taro"
                },
                "quantity": 100
            },
            {
                "goods_info": {
                    "name": "granita"
                },
                "quantity": 17
            }
        ],
        "goods_out": [
            {
                "goods_info": {
                    "name": "taro"
                },
                "quantity": 25
            },
            {
                "goods_info": {
                    "name": "taro"
                },
                "quantity": 15
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

desired output :

```
[{"name":"taro","quantity":60},{"name":"granita","quantity":17}]
```

any help please. i've try group etc

Comment: can you write, desired output as well

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya i've edited my question. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this aggregation, If `goods_ids` can have duplicates between many documents you'll have to add a `$group` stage or you'll get dup results.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$goods_in"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: "$name",
      quantity: {
        $subtract: [
          "$goods_in.quantity",
          {
            $sum: {
              $map: {
                input: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$goods_out",
                    as: "good",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$good.goods_info.name",
                        "$goods_in.goods_info.name"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                as: "item",
                in: "$$item.quantity"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZgqILvm33D8)

Answer (score 0):

by `aggregation` and `group` you can handle it,
by group stage you push the sum of out quantity in `out_value` variable,
then you join the result with first collection, on the fields with equal name by `lookup`.
and at the end of aggregation you subtract the `in_value` and `out_value`.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$unwind": "$goods_out"
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "$_id": "goods_out.name", "out_value": {"$sum": "good_out.quantity"}
            }
        },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "collection_name",
                "let": {"name": "$_id", "out_value": "$out_value", "in_value": "$goods_in.quantity"},
            "pipeline": [
                {
                  "$unwind": "$goods_in"
                },
                {
                    "$match": {

                    "$expr":
                        {"$eq": ["$$goods_in.name", "$_id"]}
                }}
            ],
            "as": "goods_info"
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind": "$goods_info"
        },
        {
            "$project":{
                "name": "$goods_info.name",
                "quantity": {
                    "$subtract": ["$goods_info.in_value", "$goods_info.in_value"]
                }
            }
        }

    ]
)
```

Comment: thanks, i've combined ur code with tom code and it works like a charm!